# threads dont seem concurrent and are not outputting unique thread ids in simple multi-threaded java program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local

I am working on a project in which 5 threads run concurrently, each dequeuing an integer from a shared queue, adding it to a thread local data structure and ultimately calculating some statistics based on the values of the integers dequeued (which range from 0 to 5 and represent 5 different colors).

The problem I am having is that the treads do not seem to be interleaving very well.  For example when I test run the program with 100 integers total in the shared queue from which each thread dequeues, I notice that often one or two threads only dequeue as few as 2 or 3 elements each while the other threads seem to dequeue many more.

It always varies which threads end up doing the most work but it seems very uneven to me.  For example on my latest test run, thread 1 only dequeued 3 total out of 100, while thread 2 dequeued 31, thread 3 dequeued 15, thread 4 dequeued 19, and thread 5 dequeued 32. This seems to indicate poor interleaving or low concurrency.

When I test run it with 10,000 elements the totals seem a little closer but still somewhat uneven with one of the threads a total number of elements in the low 200s or even slightly under 200, while another thread may dequeue as many as almost 600 elements.

The other issue is that I'm noticing that I am not able to output unique thread IDs.  Speaking of which, I have no idea why the program chose these numbers specifically, but when dequeueing elements inside the locked portion of the code, and invoking the Thread.currentThread().getId()  I do successfully get five distinct thread Ids ranging from 12 to 16 (no idea why its 12-16 and not 1-5, but whatever).

Anyway, this seems to only work within the locked portion in the RequestProcessor class.  When I attempt to invoke the Thread.currentThread.getId() method inside the toString method in my ThreadStatistic class, or anywhere else for that matter, I do not get unique thread Ids and instead get only the value 1 returned despite the fact that the ThreadLocal color counts do seem to generate a unique output for each thread.

My code is as follows:

```
public class ThreadStatistic {

private int red;
private int brown;
private int yellow;
private int green;
private int blue;

public ThreadStatistic() {
    red = 0;
    brown = 0;
    yellow = 0;
    green = 0;
    blue = 0;
}
public void update(int color) {
    switch(color) {
        case 0: 
            red++;
            break;
        case 1:
            brown++;
            break;
        case 2:
            yellow++;
            break;  
        case 3:
            green++;
            break;  
        case 4: 
            blue++;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    float total = 0;
    total += red;
    total += brown;
    total += yellow;
    total += green;
    total += blue;

    return ("\nTabulator: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count " + red + " for color Red = " + (((float)red)/total)*100 + "%" 
            + "\nTabulator: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count " + brown + " for color Brown = " + (((float)brown)/total)*100 + "%" 
            + "\nTabulator: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count " + yellow + " for color Yellow = " + (((float)yellow)/total)*100 + "%" 
            + "\nTabulator: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count " + green + " for color Green = " + (((float)green)/total)*100 + "%"
            + "\nTabulator: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count " + blue + " for color Blue = " + (((float)blue)/total)*100 + "%");
}

public float getRed() {
    return (float)red;
}

public float getBrown() {
    return (float)brown;
}

public float getYellow() {
    return (float)yellow;
}

public float getGreen() {
    return (float)green;
}

public float getBlue() {
    return (float)blue;
}
}


public class ThreadStatisticsSetup {

private static float redTotal = 0;
private static float brownTotal = 0;
private static float yellowTotal = 0;
private static float greenTotal = 0;
private static float blueTotal = 0;

private static Queue<ThreadStatistic> statsCollection = new Queue<ThreadStatistic>();

private static final ThreadLocal<ThreadStatistic> collection = new ThreadLocal<ThreadStatistic>(){
    @Override
    protected ThreadStatistic initialValue() {
        return new ThreadStatistic();}
};

    public static ThreadStatistic get() {
        return collection.get();
    }

    public static void add(ThreadStatistic result) {
        statsCollection.enqueue(result);
    }

    public static void print() {
        while(!statsCollection.isEmpty()) {
            ThreadStatistic temp = null;
            temp = statsCollection.dequeue();
            System.out.println(temp);

            redTotal += temp.getRed();
            brownTotal += temp.getBrown();
            yellowTotal += temp.getYellow();
            greenTotal += temp.getGreen();
            blueTotal += temp.getBlue();    
        }
        System.out.println("\n===TOTALS===");
        System.out.println("Color RED composes: " + (redTotal/100)*100+"%");
        System.out.println("Color BROWN composes: " + (brownTotal/100)*100+"%");
        System.out.println("Color YELLOW composes: " + (yellowTotal/100)*100+"%");
        System.out.println("Color GREEN composes: " + (greenTotal/100)*100+"%");
        System.out.println("Color BLUE composes: " + (blueTotal/100)*100+"%");
    }
}

public class RequestProcessor implements Runnable{

private Queue<Integer> mmCollection;
private ReentrantLock mmCollectionLock = new ReentrantLock();
private ReentrantLock threadStatisticLock = new ReentrantLock();

public RequestProcessor(Queue<Integer> collection) {
    mmCollection = collection;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(!mmCollection.isEmpty()) {
        int item = 0;

        try {
            mmCollectionLock.lock();
            item = mmCollection.dequeue();
            System.out.println("By thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            continue;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            mmCollectionLock.unlock();
        }   
        ThreadStatisticsSetup.get().update(item); 
    }
    try {
        threadStatisticLock.lock();
        ThreadStatisticsSetup.add(ThreadStatisticsSetup.get());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        threadStatisticLock.unlock();
    }
}
}
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue<Integer> collection = new Queue<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int mm = ((int) (Math.random() * 10000)) %5;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Integer temp = new Integer(mm);
        collection.enqueue(temp);   
    }

    RequestProcessor processor = new RequestProcessor(collection);
    int numberOfThreads = 5;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];

    for (int index = 0; index < threads.length; index++) {
        threads[index] = new Thread(processor);
        threads[index].start();
    }
    try {
        for (int index = 0; index < threads.length; index++) {
            threads[index].join();
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("Error, interrupted exception thrown");
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }   
    ThreadStatisticsSetup.print();
}
}
```

A sample output looks like the following:

```
Tabulator: 1 count 0 for color Red = 0.0%
Tabulator: 1 count 1 for color Brown = 33.333336%
Tabulator: 1 count 1 for color Yellow = 33.333336%
Tabulator: 1 count 0 for color Green = 0.0%
Tabulator: 1 count 1 for color Blue = 33.333336%

Tabulator: 1 count 7 for color Red = 22.580645%
Tabulator: 1 count 7 for color Brown = 22.580645%
Tabulator: 1 count 5 for color Yellow = 16.129032%
Tabulator: 1 count 7 for color Green = 22.580645%
Tabulator: 1 count 5 for color Blue = 16.129032%

Tabulator: 1 count 4 for color Red = 26.666668%
Tabulator: 1 count 4 for color Brown = 26.666668%
Tabulator: 1 count 2 for color Yellow = 13.333334%
Tabulator: 1 count 0 for color Green = 0.0%
Tabulator: 1 count 5 for color Blue = 33.333336%

Tabulator: 1 count 3 for color Red = 15.789473%
Tabulator: 1 count 1 for color Brown = 5.263158%
Tabulator: 1 count 4 for color Yellow = 21.052631%
Tabulator: 1 count 4 for color Green = 21.052631%
Tabulator: 1 count 7 for color Blue = 36.842106%

Tabulator: 1 count 4 for color Red = 12.5%
Tabulator: 1 count 9 for color Brown = 28.125%
Tabulator: 1 count 6 for color Yellow = 18.75%
Tabulator: 1 count 6 for color Green = 18.75%
Tabulator: 1 count 7 for color Blue = 21.875%

===TOTALS===
Color RED composes: 18.0%
Color BROWN composes: 22.0%
Color YELLOW composes: 18.0%
Color GREEN composes: 17.0%
Color BLUE composes: 25.0%
```

Comment: You are calling ThreadStatistics.toString (and in turn Thread.currentThread) from main thread and thus printing its id (you could add a field for thread id into ThreadStatistic and set it from worker). As far as dequeing goes, your threads are doing close to no work and a lot of blocking/contention.

Comment: @suff thank you for your response.  I'm still quite new to multi-threaded programming, can you please explain how I can differentiate the main thread from the child threads?  Also if my threads are doing a lot of blocking/contention, what might be a good way to alleviate this issue?  Thank you.

Comment: your main thread is your first program thread, the one on which JVM calls your program entry point (main() method of Driver class). When you call Thread.currentThread() it will return the Thread object corresponding to the thread on which that call was made (and you call print() from main). Regarding contention, your main problem  is that amount of contention you have totally shadows the amount  of work you do, look at your while loop in run(), only work you do there boils down to incrementing a variable, so your threads will mostly spend time contending for lock and dequeing.